# Gitlab, howto configure build and test be on different machines?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to gitlab and am asking for advice / best practice here.

I have a program that I build on my build machine. The program cant run on the build machine, as it needs to be installed to a test machine that has special hardware/enviornment that the program needs. I want to run some system tests (memory leak tests etc) on the test machine. How is this best done?

I think this can be accomplished with the "multi project pipeline" feature. Is this the simplest/best way?

Here is my plan:

I could have one (shh/shell) runner that build my program on my build machine, and a different runner that runs tests on my test machine. The two would be connected using "multi project pipeline" feature. The artifacts from the build pipeline would be installed on the test machine and then system tests would run on the test machine.

Is this the best way to solve this? Or is there a simpler/better way?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. "Multi project pipeline" is not necessary here. You simply have a single project and mark jobs with different "tags". You can then register runners for these different tags, on different machines.

(Artifacts are transferred from one job to the next the same, regardless if the runners are run on the same machine or on different ones)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags